# rounding off and comparing value when using currency rate

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say i have this situation. I have a bid system that accept different currency rate. Here is my situation.

- I have a minimum value that i need to submit for my bid to be acceptable. Let's   say MYR 501,000.0000. This is the base rate.
- But i pick the bid currency of SGD which is SGD 2.5694. So the minimum value that i need to submit is MYR 194987.1565. Using the formula 501000 * (1/2.5694)
- And the system will calculate the bid that i submitted with exchange rate. 194987.1565 * 2.5694 = 500999.9999111
- And then the system will compare with the minimum value in base rate to determine if the bid is accepted. In my case 500999.9999111 when round off to 4 decimal point will be 500999.9999. And this is less than the minimum value which is 501000.0000 so the bid is rejected.

So my question is how can i tackle this situation? As i need to compare the bid submitted in base rate. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: "i need to submit is MYR 194987.1565. Using the formula 501000 * (1/2.5694)" this statement is wrong, it should be 194987.1565345995 or 194987.1566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure someone else will give you a better answer, but one approach would be to define some tolerance (or [epsilon value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit)), such as ± 0.001, and use that in your validation tests to allow for negligible differences due to conversion and rounding.

Comment: yes. i have decided to do something like this. thanks for the respond anyway. thank you!